# jps command not found in ubuntu 16.04 while installing hadoop

Tags: hadoop2

```
rana@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/bin$ start-yarn.sh
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/yarn-rana-resourcemanager-ubuntu.out
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/yarn-rana-nodemanager-ubuntu.out
rana@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/bin$ jps
The program 'jps' can be found in the following packages:
 * openjdk-8-jdk-headless
 * openjdk-9-jdk-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
rana@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/bin$ sudo jps
sudo: jps: command not found
```

i was trying to install hadoop, at the end i got an error of jps command not found

anyone please help me with this
thank you

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I solved my issue by entering the following :-

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless
```

Hope this one helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add `JAVA_HOME/bin` address to your PATH at the environment file, I mean `bashrc`. So use the command `nano ~/.bashrc` open the environment file and add then line `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH` at the end of the file and save it by pressing `control + x`. After closing the file use command `source ~/.bashrc` to compile file and update to new setting. Now `JPS` command will works!

Comment: @Rana Arepalli  Pls check it as correct answer if it helped, for future readers.